# Is there a way to separate the chains belong to each Biological assembly in a PDB file?(python Script)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to separate the chain IDs which belong to specific Biological assemblies in a PDB file. 
As an Example PDB ID 1BRS has 3 Biological assemblies 
Biological assembly 1 : - chains A and D
Biological assembly 2 : - Chains B and E
Biological assembly 3 : - chains C and F

Is there a way (python Script) to get the Chain IDs separate which belong to each biological assembly as follows
1BRS_A:D
1BRS_B:E
1BRS_C:F
No need to extract the chain coordinates. If I get the chain names, that will be enough.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDBx/mmCIF file format contains the information in the `_pdbx_struct_assembly_gen` category.

```
loop_
_pdbx_struct_assembly_gen.assembly_id 
_pdbx_struct_assembly_gen.oper_expression 
_pdbx_struct_assembly_gen.asym_id_list 
1 1 A,D,G,J 
2 1 B,E,H,K 
3 1 C,F,I,L
```

These files can be read e.g. with *Biotite* (https://www.biotite-python.org/), a package I am developing.
The categories can be read in a dictionary-like manner:

```py
import biotite.database.rcsb as rcsb
import biotite.structure as struc
import biotite.structure.io.pdbx as pdbx

ID = "1BRS"

# Download structure
file_name = rcsb.fetch(ID, "pdbx", target_path=".")

# Read file
file = pdbx.PDBxFile()
file.read(file_name)
# Get 'pdbx_struct_assembly_gen' category as dictionary
assembly_dict = file["pdbx_struct_assembly_gen"]
for asym_id_list in assembly_dict["asym_id_list"]:
    chain_ids = asym_id_list.split(",")
    print(f"{ID}_{':'.join(chain_ids)}")
```

The output is

```
1BRS_A:D:G:J
1BRS_B:E:H:K
1BRS_C:F:I:L
```

The chains G-L contain only water molecules.

EDIT:

To include only chain IDs that belong to a polymer, e.g. a protein or a nucleotide, you can use the `entity_poly` category:

```
loop_
_entity_poly.entity_id 
_entity_poly.type 
_entity_poly.nstd_linkage 
_entity_poly.nstd_monomer 
_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code 
_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code_can 
_entity_poly.pdbx_strand_id 
_entity_poly.pdbx_target_identifier 
1 'polypeptide(L)' no no 
;AQVINTFDGVADYLQTYHKLPDNYITKSEAQALGWVASKGNLADVAPGKSIGGDIFSNREGKLPGKSGRTWREADINYTS
GFRNSDRILYSSDWLIYKTTDHYQTFTKIR
;
;AQVINTFDGVADYLQTYHKLPDNYITKSEAQALGWVASKGNLADVAPGKSIGGDIFSNREGKLPGKSGRTWREADINYTS
GFRNSDRILYSSDWLIYKTTDHYQTFTKIR
;
A,B,C ? 
2 'polypeptide(L)' no no 
;KKAVINGEQIRSISDLHQTLKKELALPEYYGENLDALWDALTGWVEYPLVLEWRQFEQSKQLTENGAESVLQVFREAKAE
GADITIILS
;
;KKAVINGEQIRSISDLHQTLKKELALPEYYGENLDALWDALTGWVEYPLVLEWRQFEQSKQLTENGAESVLQVFREAKAE
GADITIILS
;
D,E,F ?
```

This is the updated Python code:

```py
import biotite.database.rcsb as rcsb
import biotite.structure as struc
import biotite.structure.io.pdbx as pdbx

ID = "1BRS"

# Download structure
file_name = rcsb.fetch(ID, "pdbx", target_path=".")

# Read file
file = pdbx.PDBxFile()
file.read(file_name)

# Get 'entity_poly' category as dictionary
# to find out which chains are polymers
poly_chains = []
for chain_list in file["entity_poly"]["pdbx_strand_id"]:
    poly_chains += chain_list.split(",")

# Get 'pdbx_struct_assembly_gen' category as dictionary
for asym_id_list in file["pdbx_struct_assembly_gen"]["asym_id_list"]:
    chain_ids = asym_id_list.split(",")
    # Filter chains that belong to a polymer
    chain_ids = [chain_id for chain_id in chain_ids if chain_id in poly_chains]
    print(f"{ID}_{':'.join(chain_ids)}")
```

And this is the output:

```
1BRS_A:D
1BRS_B:E
1BRS_C:F
```

Comment: This is perfect. Is there any way that i can get the answer without the HETATM. Thanks for the reply

Comment: it's great to have some examples of Biotite usage here on SO, but since you seem to be the main developer of the package, you should probably declare this, e.g. see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers/

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Thank you for this information, I was not aware of this policy. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @bro: I edited my answer, now only polymer chains are considered

Comment: @PadixKey This is  Perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code! It works nicely with serveral assemblies. But if the entry has only a single assembly it does not recognize it properly. Updated it to this:

```
import biotite.database.rcsb as rcsb
import biotite.structure as struc
import biotite.structure.io.pdbx as pdbx
import json
ID = "3AV2"
#ID= "1BRS"
ID="2k6d"
#ID="1TBE"
ID="1HT2"
#ID="1HTI"
# Download structure
file_name = rcsb.fetch(ID, "pdbx", target_path=".")

# Read file
file = pdbx.PDBxFile()
file.read(file_name)

# Get 'entity_poly' category as dictionary
# to find out which chains are polymers
poly_chains = []
if isinstance(file["entity_poly"]["pdbx_strand_id"],str):
   poly_chains=file["entity_poly"]["pdbx_strand_id"].split(",")
else:
   for chain_list in file["entity_poly"]["pdbx_strand_id"]:
      poly_chains += chain_list.split(",")

biolAssemblyDict={}
if isinstance(file["pdbx_struct_assembly_gen"]["asym_id_list"],str):
    index=0
    asym_id_list=file["pdbx_struct_assembly_gen"]["asym_id_list"]
    chain_ids=asym_id_list.split(",")
    chain_ids = [chain_id for chain_id in chain_ids if chain_id in poly_chains]
    biolAssemblyDict[index+1]= ','.join(chain_ids)
else:
    # Get 'pdbx_struct_assembly_gen' category as dictionary
    for index,asym_id_list in enumerate(file["pdbx_struct_assembly_gen"]["asym_id_list"]):
        chain_ids = asym_id_list.split(",")
        #    print(chain_ids)
        # Filter chains that belong to a polymer
        chain_ids = [chain_id for chain_id in chain_ids if chain_id in poly_chains]
        biolAssemblyDict[index+1]= ','.join(chain_ids)
print(json.dumps(biolAssemblyDict,indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```